# How can I hide identifier names in compiled projects?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

When I compile a project containg code such as:

```
ttest = record
   one, two: string;
   three: integer;
end;
```

I can see in the EXE strings like "ttest", "one", "two", and "three".

This is in any verion of Delphi, even in Free Pascal.

Is there any possibility to not put this in the compiled program? Without using packers, encrypters, or the like.

Comment: are you building a release version since it sounds more like a debug version unless those names are constant values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Using "string" in records causes that the record name is visible in executable

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off every kind of debug information you can find in the Project Options dialog (menu item **Project/Options**), then rebuild the whole project (i.e. not just **Compile**, use the **Project/Build** menu item so that every unit in the project is recompiled). That should fix it.

The actual options you have to deselect in the project options depend on your Delphi version: for Delphi 2006/Turbo Delphi, these include all options under **Debugging** on the **Compiler** tab (maybe except *"Assertions"*) and on the **Linker** tab *"Include TD32 debug info"* / *"Include remote debug symbols"*. Newer Delphi versions have a "Build Configuration" feature similar to Visual Studio, selecting "Release" here and rebuilding should remove all "telltale" debugging information.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This didnt work, i turned off just everything in project options and it still exists in the EXE. As long as i use Delphi i never found how to remove this. I can overwrite those strings with WinHex and program runs normally - no crashes or such, but the problem is that anyone can read my data structures, which can help, for example, crack the app.

Comment: Are you sure it is exactly for the example you give? Published properties are always RTTIed!!!!! So that you see _some_ fieldnames is normal. Avoid making them published if you don't want that (but the VCL partially relies on that)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that this will help, but check out [create smaller delphi xe executable](http://delphi.about.com/b/2011/07/26/create-smaller-delphi-xe-executables-remove-rtti-pack-exe.htm), it seems like removing the `RTTI` could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid to put your data as *published*, if possible, otherwise fields names are visible. Additionally, don't forget that every method created when cliking the property inspector is automatically put as published (because they are also used in the dfm files). So each 'Button1Click' etc is visible and therefore easily localizable (method code).

Just check any program compiled with Delphi in IDA free and with the special 'Delphi string IDC script (find it at the IDA palace)'.In the *Names* window you'll easy see every *TSomething*, every *TSomething published properties* and *methods*...